# Conversion of hashbytes output to integer allowed?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I have some code with the following lines:

```
CAST(HASHBYTES('MD5', 'some long string with up to 256 characters') AS int)
CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'some very very long string...') AS int)
```

This has been done to generate a unique int value and later the int value is used as a lookup key (or foreign key in a join). So my best guess to why it's done this way is make the join quicker an be able to generate an index (and not run into the 900 bytes limit there).

But I'm unsure if the above output will not create much more collisions when converting it to int.

My understanding is that it is not possible to represent an MD5 hash or even a SHA-256 hash as an int value...

The code originally was developed on SQL-Server 2008. I currently use SQL-Server 2014.

Comment: So you just need a unique INT value?  Can't you use an incrementing identity?

Comment: I need the uniqueness of the int based on the string. So the same string should give the same int-value.

Comment: _"same string -> same int"_? how is that? considering `int` is still 4 bytes long.

Comment: It did work up to now because the strings were short and I guess maybe pure coincidence based on the internal casting to int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will create much more collisions. An `int` is only 4 bytes (32 bits), whereas `MD5` generates 20 (160 bits) and `SHA2_256` 32 (256 bits). Less bits means less unique values so more collisions.

Technically it *is* allowed...